# How do I create a package of my application in VB.net which can run on other's systems too?

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, static, linker

I made an application in Visual Studio 2012 using VB.net language.

I want to make a package or a setup so that any user **whether they have visual studios or not** can run my application.

I searched on internet and what I found is that there is something like **statically** or dynamically linking. Do these relate to my question?

Please give me a step by step method of packaging so that my application can run on Windows without needing Visual Studio or any other program to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it in the menu under `Build` -> `Publish`.

This will produce an executable that can be run without Visual Studio. The .NET Framework has to be installed on the computer though, but that usually is.

Comment: @architjn: What do you mean?

Comment: when i run it it only work once properly and then starts working abnormally....
is there any other way!!

Comment: @architjn: In what way does it work abnormally? Publishing an application is the normal way of producing an executable.